# pacemaker agent nvmet-subsystem missing

Tags: pacemaker, nvme

I tried to follow the drbd Howto "Highly Available NVMe Over Fabrics (NVMe-oF) on RHEL 9", but run into the error

```
`Error: Unable to find agent 'nvmet-subsystem', try specifying its full name`
`Error: Errors have occurred, therefore pcs is unable to continue`
```

It happend with the command:
`pcs -f nvmet_config resource create p_nvme-subsystem_0 nvmet-subsystem \ nqn=linbit-nqn0 \ op start timeout=10s interval=0 \ op stop timeout=10s interval=0 \ op monitor interval=10s timeout=10s`

So I have no experience with pacemaker, but i think it requests the NVMe-oF target export agent, that is located in the package "resource-agents". So I installed it additionally although it was not specified. But no change.
I found this overview according agents:
[pcs example for nvme-subsystem](https://www.mankier.com/7/ocf_heartbeat_nvmet-subsystem#Example_PCS)
So I changed the command to:
 `pcs -f nvmet_config resource create nvme-subsystem_0 ocf:heartbeat:nvmet-subsystem nqn=drbd-nvme1 op......`
 Also not working.
I tried this Howto with Rocky 9, Ubuntu Server 22.04 and Debian 11.3. All give the same error message.
Clear is that the Howto is not correct, but how can i fix this? I found not one post in the internet according this. Strange. I dont think that i am the first, because Linbit do it already.

Answer (score 3):

There’s no point to proceed this route either way as DRBD kills NVMe performance during replication. You need some 100% user-mode application doing polling and avoiding interrupt processing overhead, thread context switches, and user-to-kernel (and back) jumps. Nothing living in kernel would fully unleash NVMe potential. Say SPDK NVMe-oF target might be a way better choice.

https://spdk.io/releases/

EDIT: Replaced commercial Lightbits with open-source SPDK.

Comment: no advertising, please

Comment: I don’t have anything to do with the Lightbits guys. Replaced the link with an open-source SPDK though.

Comment: Nice to Know there exist a opensource Framework. The performance charts are impressiv. I like that there is support for compression on blocklevel. For my understanding SPDK uses nvme internally so u can not use normal SAS-HDDs. Right?

Comment: That was not formulated correctly. I mean SPDK uses the nvme-protocol for "disks".

Comment: You can absolutely attach to the aio-exposed Linux kernel block devices. We’ve did it even with a spinning disks (just don’t ask why…), so kernel-managed NVMe shouldn’t be an issue. Just make sure there’s no root file system mounted on top of it.